# Why is the determinant of any triangular matrix always the multiple of the main diagonal?

Tags: matrices, determinant

Is there a mathematical proof or a conclusion explaining as to why it is that?

Comment: Because in the $-$ say (upper)-triangular $-$ matrix, besides the product of the terms on the main diagonal, every term $a_{1,i_1}a_{2,i_2}...a_{n,i_n}$ in determinant's defining sum is zero, since one of the term's entries $a_{j,i_j}$ lies below the main diagonal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand along the row/column with maximum number of zeroes.
You might need induction to prove this.

Answer (score 1):

For an $n\times n$ upper triangular matrix,
$$
U=\begin{bmatrix}u_{11} & u_{12}^* \\ 0 & U_{22}\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $U_{22}$ is $(n-1)\times(n-1)$, we have using the Leibniz formula that
$$
\det(U)=u_{11}\det(U_{22}).
$$
Now use induction.